# Configuring and using XA transactions with WebSphere MQ V7.5 Classes for Java using MySql v5.7

Tags: java, mysql, ibm-mq, ubuntu-16.04, xa

I was looking into configuring a 2 phase commit between my MQ Put and MySql write operation. A little bit of research led me to XA enabled MQ managers which have a datasource configured and hence can operate the MQ and DB under the same UOW.

Here is a sample code flow of what i wanted to achieve:

```
MQBEGIN 
MQPUT (include the flag MQPMO_SYNCPOINT in the message options) 
SQL INSERT 
MQCMIT
```

However, i see that MySql is not on the list of the supported DBs for IBM Websphere MQ v7.5. I would need the  XA switch files for my stack (Ubuntu 16.04 64bit, IBM MQ v7.5 , MySQL v5.7) right? Has anyone synced up these before? Would really like some help setting up these queues.

Any suggestions on a better way to have a 2PC between a IBM MQ and MySql DB?

Comment: Did my answer help you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use MQ as a XA Transaction Manager, there probably is not a way to have it coordinate with MySQL as a Resource Manager.

I did however find a open source project called LIXA that is a transaction manager which claims to work with IBM MQ as a Resource Manager.  It also says it can use MySql as a Resource Manager.

Here is the post with some more information I found on the IBM developerWorks WebSphere MQ Forum: "[LIXA 0.7.3 tested with WebSphere MQ 7.1](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014803697)".

Further examples on configuring LIXA with IBM MQ can be found on the following LIXA documentation pages:

1. [An example with WebSphere MQ](http://lixa.sourceforge.net/lixa-doc/html/ch05s14.html)
2. [An example with WebSphere MQ, MySQL and PostgreSQL](http://lixa.sourceforge.net/lixa-doc/html/ch05s15.html)